# SpringBoot2 how can I load newly added resources when running

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a web program.

In a controller, I create a picture using JfreeChart and save in /resources/image/.

But I can't load it on the web page immediately yet I can see the file under the directory. About 10s later, it can be loaded.

I'm not sure if I need to refresh resources in my code, And how should I refresh if needed.

Comment: Notice that the SpringBoot app needs time to startup and to begin the port listening and HTTP request handling.

Comment: Resources are packaged in the jar file so you can't add to that folder at run time. Use a different folder and read the file as an external one to the application.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It is really useful. Thanks! @Juan